# How to access a resource file using relative path in play framework project?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-1.x

My play framework project uses resource files like CSV files that I have under resources directory which I created under play project root directly so it is at the same level as other directories like app, public etc.  From within Java or Scala files how can I open such files using path that is relative to the project root? This path should also work when I create a war and deploy the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [VirtualFile](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.1/play/vfs/VirtualFile.html) class should do everything you need, especially the method 'fromRelativePath()'.

```
VirtualFile vf = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("filename.csv");
```

Comment: is this valid for play 2.0 as well?

Comment: @harmanjd [Use Play.getExistingFile()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12596981/1708136)