# Parse images directory

Tags: java, playframework

I'm working with [play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) and i have a problem with my deployed application on [playapps.net](http://www.playapps.net/) that i haven't localy.
Here his my code :

```
public static void image(Long idCategorieProject, Long idImage)
{

    CategorieProject categorieproject = CategorieProject.findById(idCategorieProject);
    List<Categorie> categories = Categorie.all().fetch();

    // SMALL IMAGES
    List<String>smallImages = null;
    try
    {
        File dirSmall = new File("public/images/projects/"+idCategorieProject+"/small/");
        smallImages = new ArrayList();
        File[] smallImageFiles = dirSmall.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < smallImageFiles.length; i++) {
            smallImages.add(smallImageFiles[i].getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // FULL IMAGE
    List<String>fullImages = null;
    try
    {
        File dirSmall = new File("public/images/projects/"+idCategorieProject+"/full/");
        fullImages = new ArrayList();
        File[] fullImageFiles = dirSmall.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < fullImageFiles.length; i++) {
            if (i == idImage)
                fullImages.add(fullImageFiles[i].getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    render(lang, categorieproject, categories, fullImages, smallImages);
}
```

Localy, my images arrays are not null and I can display them, but with the deploy version, it's seems that arrays are null. Is there another solution to parse an image directory ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths for your files, which may cause issues depending where the application is executed from.

You would be safer using the VirtualFile (play.vfs.VirtualFile) object that is available within core Play, and using the `fromRelativePath(String path)` method.

For more information you can check out this post - [How to access a resource file using relative path in play framework project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430765/how-to-access-a-resource-file-using-relative-path-in-play-framework-project), or simply searching for `VirtualFile [Playframework]` in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem listing files when the app is deployed as opposed to when it is run locally then maybe it is a permission problem.