# How do I access a resource file using a relative path in Play Framework 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

How do I access a resource file relative to a Play application path (even when packaged into a distribution zip)?

This is the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6430765/303106), but in Play 2, which has no VirtualFile class in its api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out `play.api.Play.getFile()` and `play.api.Play.getExistingFile()`, which get files from the file system relative to the application directory.

A similar technique that works for me is simply to add a resource directory (or jar) to the classpath in the play start script. I can then use Play.getResourceAsStream() to load files from that directory, or specify the resource as a JVM parameter in the start script (e.g. `-Dconfig.resource=/my_conf/prd.conf`)

Comment: Is it possible to locate a file via: `val f = java.io.File("../../test/A.xml")`? If there's no active `application`, then what do you do?

Comment: link to scaladoc: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Play$